# При добавлении инфоблока ломается кодировка

Tags: битрикс, 1с

Столкнулся с такой проблемой, установил на ubuntu "bitrix создание сайта". Добавил поля которые можно изменять в режиме правке и уже там при добавлении новой надписи на русском , ломается кодировка. Тоже самое происходит при добавлении инфоблока, что мне с эти сделать? В mysql по дефолту установил кодировку utf-8 general ci, все таблицы bitrix в кодировке utf8_unicode_ci. Как я понял это проблема именно в передаче данных в таблицу и считывания данных с неё. Т.к инфоблоки хранят данные в бд. Вот что с кодировкой:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Проверьте настройки подключения к базе данных:

- /bitrix/php_interface/dbconn.php
- /bitrix/php_interface/after_connect.php
- /bitrix/php_interface/after_connect_d7.php

Возможно там имеются противоречащие директивы. Запустите тестирование системы на странице /bitrix/admin/site_checker.php?lang=ru - возможно тестирование выявит ошибки в базе данных.